# Does "crawling" absent incase of slip-ring induction motor?

Tags: induction-motor, electric-machine

In case of wound rotor induction motor no. of stator & rotor pole must be same otherwise the motor will not operate. Please can anybody explain the physical reason behind it. As the no. of stator and rotor pole must be same, is it true that for wound rotor "Crawling" will not occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation of an induction motor depends on the magnetic fields of the rotor and stator moving with a fixed angular displacement from each other just as they do in a synchronous motor. Each pole of the rotor magnetic field exerts force on a pole of the rotor magnetic field as they rotate at synchronous speed. However the speed of the rotor itself is lower than the speed of the magnetic fields.

In a squirrel-cage motor, the stator field creates a rotor magnetic field with a matching number of poles without any pole configuration being designed into the rotor. With a wound-rotor motor, the windings must have a phase and pole configuration to accommodate the external part of the rotor circuit. That configuration must match the stator configuration so that the required configuration of matching magnetic field poles is maintained.

Crawling is an undesirable performance phenomenon caused by the relative configurations of stator slots and rotor slots. The design of the slot configurations must be able to accommodate the overall winding design, but the winding of poles in the rotor doesn't directly reduce the possibility of crawling in a wound-rotor motor. What does reduce the possibility of crawling is the higher starting torque of the wound-rotor motor. That makes it less likely that any torque introduced by the slot configuration will cause the overall torque vs. speed curve to drop below the torque vs. speed curve of the connected load.